# How do I make wget properly quiet?

Tags: windows, wget

wget always echoes system values to the console, even when I specify -q (quiet) on the command line, e.g.:

```
C:\> wget -q http://www.google.com/
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc

C:\>
```

How do I make the noise stop?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

that should work:

```
%> wget.exe parameters_here  1> NUL 2> NUL
```

Comment: Instead of `NUL` you should used `/dev/null`.  Unless, of course, you expect to find the noise in a file called 'NUL'.

Comment: `> NUL` for windows, `> /dev/null` for *nix.

Answer (score 13):

Try adding a `>NUL`:

```
wget -q http://www.google.com/ >NUL
```

Answer (score 6):

The more I rely on wget the more annoying these messages get.   Appears to be a bug in wget **version 1.11.4** (details [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/forums/forum/131144/topic/3937915)), a 2008 vintage that is still the "latest" binary for Windows.  I prefer this work-around:

```
wget  ...parameters...  2>>wgeterr.log
```

@akira 2>NUL makes the two lines go away, but I'm concerned what other error messages it may suppress.  The following do not work: >NUL (output is to stderr) nor -q, nor -nv.

Comment: my 1.11.4 works fine.  try getting it from gnuwin32 again  They (THE Gnuwin32 SOURCEFORGE LINK) you mention   also mentions Christopher Lewis's wget download page but it seems to be down.

Comment: I use the --no-verbose option. It shows just the names of the files being downloaded.   [-q,  --quiet                     quiet (no output)
  -v,  --verbose                   be verbose (this is the default)
  -nv, --no-verbose                turn off verboseness, without being quiet]. Usage: wget -nv  (other options) url

Comment: @Polymath I mentioned that -nv didn't work for me, which probably meant that it didn't suppress that extra output. That's just an alias for --no-verbose isn't it? I don't recall my use case so I can't check.